# Como usar funciones en listas para python?

Tags: python, funciones, bucle-for

Estaba trabajando con una lista de datos y me interesaba sumar los 4 primeros datos de esa lista y dividirlos entre 2, luego agarrar los siguientes 4 y hacer la misma operacion, despues omitir los 2 primeros y agarrar los siguientes 4, y asi...

```
A1 = 15
A2 = 16
A3 = 17
A4 = 18
A5 = 19
A6 = 20
Aces = [A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6]
```

Estaba pensando en hacer una funcion con un ciclo for, pero no sé como omitir el primer valor, luego omitir los siguientes 2 y asi.
Igual si alguien tiene una manera mas eficiente de hacer esta operacion soy todo oidos :))

Comment: Mas bien todo ojos porque lo vas a leer, haha. Cuando hagas una pregunta es importante siempre mostrar lo que has intentado aunque no funcione. En este único caso he decidido responder ya que el comentario que estaba escribiendo para orientarte sobre una opción para hacerlo era muy largo y sin mostrar código iba a ser algo confuso pero ten en cuenta que las preguntas que no muestran el código que has intentado utilizar normalmente son ignoradas, cerradas y/o votadas negativamente. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas graciaaas, es que habia escrito un codigo muy simple y no estaba seguro de ponerlo haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es crear dos ciclos `for` anidados para recorrer la lista de 4 en 4 con ayuda de `range()`

Muestra con un ejemplo genérico:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

grupo = 4
limite = len(x) - grupo + 1

for i in range(limite):
    for j in range(i, i + grupo):
        print(x[j])
    print('------')
```

Como desconozco si en algun momento el tamaño del grupo se vaya a modificar lo he puesto en una variable. El punto importante es encontrar hasta que punto se debe recorrer la lista ya que si no consideramos el límite se intentaría acceder a índices de la lista que no existen.

Esto devuelve:

```
0
1
2
3
------
1
2
3
4
------
2
3
4
5
------
3
4
5
6
------
4
5
6
7
------
5
6
7
8
------
6
7
8
9
------
```

### Edición

**Nota:** El ejemplo anterior era solo para mostrar una idea de como podrías recorrer tu lista, al ver tu respuesta decidí hacer la edición para mostrar otro método que te será de utilidad.

Puedes utilizar `slices` ([Rebanadas](https://programmerclick.com/article/3791922168/)) en combinación con `sum()`:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

grupo = 4
limite = len(x) - grupo + 1

for i in range(limite):
    print(sum(x[i:i+grupo])/2)
```

Otra forma más compacta sería utilizar una comprensión de listas y el argumento `sep` de `print`:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

grupo = 4
limite = len(x) - grupo + 1

print(*[sum(x[i:i+grupo])/2 for i in range(limite)], sep='\n')
```

El resultado en ambos casos es:

```
3.0
5.0
7.0
9.0
11.0
13.0
15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

ya solamente falto hacer la suma y división al final

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

grupo = 4
limite = len(a) - grupo + 1

for i in range(limite):
    for j in range(i, i + grupo):
        print(x[j])
    z=(a[i]+a[i+1]+a[i+2]+a[i+3])/2
    print(z)
    print('------')
```

Para que devuelva:

```
 Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
 0
 1
 2
 3
 3.0
 ------
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5.0
 ------
 2
 3
 4
 5
 7.0
 ------
 ...
 8
 9
 15.0
 ------
```

Muy buena respuesta Heytale.

Comment: Buen día, la respuesta que puse era una idea de como recorrer la lista, he editado mi respuesta y he puesto un par de soluciones más cortas de lo que querías hacer utilizando `slices`

Comment: Buen código, muchas gracias por tu tiempo respondiéndome mi pregunta :))